# How do implement an API controller into existing ASP.NET MVC Project?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a .NET Core website. It uses ASP.NET Identity. I am now building a Xamarin app for the site. I have implemented a token issuer action into the existing Account Controller so i can make authorised calls to the site.

```
// POST: /Account/Token
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Token(LoginViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
            if (user != null)
            {

                var result = await _signInManager.CheckPasswordSignInAsync
                                (user, model.Password, lockoutOnFailure: false);

                if (!result.Succeeded)
                {
                    return Unauthorized();
                }

                var claims = new[]
                {
                    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, model.Email),
                    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
                };

                var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("A Super Security Key"));
                var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

                var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                    issuer: "Issuer",
                    audience: "IssuerA",
                    claims: claims,
                    expires: DateTime.Now.AddDays(7),
                    signingCredentials: creds);
                return Ok(new { token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token) });

                //return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
            }
        }
            return BadRequest("Could not verify username and password");
    }
```

This appears to work. I can get a token via a postman request.

So, I now need implement a controller to make my app calls to with the token. I have tried to add a standard controller -

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    //[Authorize]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult Test()
    {
        return Ok("test");
    }
}
```

This only gets called if i AllowAnonymous. If i enable the Authorize it wont return me unauthorised or even enter it with a token included in the request.

I think i should probably be adding an API controller somehow, is that correct? How do i go about doing this? Any other suggestions welcome. This is my current layout:

[image]

Comment: In .net core both MVC and API controllers inherit from a single class called Controller. There is no more ApiController class. So that is not your problem it's something else...

Comment: From the information you've provided, this sounds like you just have an issue with `Authorize` not working - Can you prove that is not the case?

Comment: @mason if i add a new API Project, where would i configure the JWT issuer? Could that stay in the current project and dish the tokens out, then i use the tokens to access the API actions?

Comment: @KirkLarkin Good point. If i pass the token but still AllowAnonymous I can see that in the user property, it has no claims, IsAuthenticated is also false. Perhaps something to do with the token code?

Comment: You need to process the token via an authorization handler. It's built in but needs configuring. My guess is you just have the Cookie authentication scheme, but you'll also need to add e.g. the Bearer scheme and corresponding JwtBearer services. Have a look at using JwtBearer in ASP.NET Core. [This](https://auth0.com/blog/securing-asp-dot-net-core-2-applications-with-jwts/) might help with part of that.

Comment: You can implement a custom filter ex: `[TokenAuthenticate]` [check this article for details](https://blog.zaven.co/user-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-rsa-jwt-tokens-part-4/)